# Moderator Primary does not Remember if you already Voted

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderators

Minor bug, but I thought I'd report it all the same -- whenever you go to the moderator primary page, the page doesn't remember who you voted for.

You can perform another up/down vote, but this second vote isn't counted.

e.g., I vote for Tzenes, giving him 1 up vote. Several hours later, I come back, and click on the moderator primary thread again. Tzenes has 1 up vote (from me), but I can up vote him again (which *appears* to bring him up to 2 votes). If I refresh the page, Tzenes still has 1 vote, and once again I can 'vote' again.

Again, minor, but inconsistent with the rest of the stack exchange sites.

Comment: Yep, happens for me too.

Comment: @Raven can you verify that this is still happening?  I'm having trouble reproducing this.

Comment: @Geoff, it happens to me too (still)

Comment: @Geoff - I am now no longer to vote for anyone, even those I have yet to vote for.

Comment: @Geoff I'll round off the conflicting reports - I can still vote for everyone, and still undo any of my votes.

Comment: @Raven - I pushed a new build that has a few missing cache breakers, could you check again please?  If it's not working meet me in the chat.

Comment: Fixed for me @Geoff, I can even split votes in up/down which I also couldn't do (I need to find out which 7 users downvoted me and ban them though)

Comment: @Geoff [I could repro this yesterday](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/501633#501633), then for some reason it fixed itself in the matter of minutes.

Comment: @Geoff -- the issue is now fixed, thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bug long since fixed and implemented.